# kUbuntu 22.04 long time not used, update dist-upgrade, maybe did restart later 10 minutes says security updates ready. Why they didnt install in 1 go?

Tags: apt, updates, kubuntu, update-manager

kUbuntu 22.04 long time not used, update dist-upgrade, maybe did restart later 10 minutes says security updates ready. Why they didnt install in 1 go?

First time saw something like this, that installed WITH APT one updates total 1000mb will take then system notification pops up 10 minutes later says theres more- this time security updates again, So i opened again terminal and disct-upgrade says again 1000mb will take.

Why they all didnt update in one go?